# How to balance Canon 750D with 70-300mm lens on a small tripod?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod

I have ordered a [Neewer 50 cm (20 inch) mini tripod](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MSAEZN8) for my Canon 750D and [EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 IS II USM](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/lenses/ef/telephoto-zoom/ef-70-300mm-f-4-5-6-is-ii-usm) lens. The tripod is suitable for up to 5 kg. However, I am not sure that the weight is the problem, most probably the problem will be the length of the lens when at 300mm, which is when I need a tripod the most.

Note that the lens does not have a tripod foot.

Are my worries unjustified, or is there some other accessory I need to balance the camera and lens on the tripod?

Comment: Just be sure to really tight the head. If it is lose the camera will simply fall.

Comment: Btw, you canon is a 750D :) the D750 is a very pricey Nikon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the lens has its own tripod mount ring, the whole thing can be very unbalanced and tip over.

If your lens comes without one you can find adaptable rings but you need free space on the barrel (not on your lens it seems). Otherwise you have to use a mount plate between your lens and the camera, to shift the center of gravity backwards (but these are hard to find at economical prices).

Comment: This https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-70-300mm-f-4-5.6-IS-II-USM-Lens.aspx is the lens. It has no mount ring. Do I have to consider anything with regard to the compatibility to the tripod?

Comment: No, these use the same thread as the camera body, so if you tripod head takes your camera, it will take the mount ring. However, I don't see how your lens can take a ring mount.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can do.

1. Increase your stability. Spread the tripod's legs to a wider stance to increase the footprint of the tripod. This way, even if the center of mass of the camera+lens combination is for forward of the ballhead's center, the center of mass is well inside of the triangle described by the tripod's feet. In general, the closer the center of mass is to the center of this triangle, the more stable your setup is.
2. Use a different quick release plate to connect your camera to the tripod. If you get a longer QR plate for the tripod's ballhead, you can use it to set the camera back behind the ballhead, putting the center of mass of the camera+lens combo over the center of the ballhead. For example, this [Haoge 120mm QR plate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Z40X37I) would probably work (note that the greyed-out ballhead is not part of the plate). This plate is about $20 on Amazon. With some searching, you should probably be able to find a similar plate either elsewhere, or from another manufacturer, for less.

   [image]
   <sup>Haoge 120mm QR plate</sup>
3. The drawback with just getting a longer baseplate as suggested above, is you’re not taking advantage of the whole reason for using QR plates in the first place: if you leave a QR plate always attached to your camera, you can *quickly release* it from the tripod. In order to leave the QR plate that came with the tripod always attached to your camera, you need a **nodal slide** clamp (sometimes also called a fore-and-aft clamp). For example, this [Neewer nodal slide clamp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J7LT4FA) would work, instead of getting the longer plate in #2 above.

[image: Neewer nodal slide clamp]

Comment: The plates can be fairly cheap. The heads that accept Arca style plates, on the other hand...

Comment: @MichaelClark As long as the Arca-style clamps are screw-type, then they'll accept pretty much any Arca-style plate. Most Sirui, Neewer, Sunpak, and other such inexpensive tripods and ballheads have screw-type Arca-style clamps. I have a small handful of different cheap ballheads and clamps from these manufacturers, and they all accept plates from RRS, Novoflex, Hejnar Photo, Kirk, etc.

Comment: The tripod OP links to appears to accept the plate pictured in this answer.

Comment: I ended up ordering this: https://www.amazon.com/Neewer-Professional-Release-Camera-Compatible/dp/B00J7LT4ZK/ref=pd_cp_421_1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=fcaa6d12-8b2b-4ad7-b277-864b2da79f6e&pf_rd_r=F8MVJA5TS21KM8MZBGGM&pd_rd_wg=e9BTY&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&pd_rd_w=kWrMr&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pd_rd_r=f2475c09-a536-11e8-8ca5-3701795e9eab&pd_rd_i=B00J7LT4ZK&psc=1&refRID=F8MVJA5TS21KM8MZBGGM . I will leave a comment when it arrives.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but this combination still works like a charm.

Comment: @user76223 that’s great. I found that once I started into the QR system, it was easy to find excuses to get more (such as a small clamp left attached to my sling strap for carrying the camera, etc.)